# How can I minimize -p-value in python provided by the kstest of one distribution based on data price return?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am trying to download from pandas datareader library the stock price and calculate the (daily, weekly,monthly,etc...) return based on the ticker that I provide.

After downloading the data, I execute a kstest at the distribution of this data and evaluate if it is similar to a bi-normal distribution (sum of two normal distribution) based on the p-value provided.

Since I am executing only one kstest for this distribution I want to maximize the p-value(minimize -p-value) utilizing the "minimize" library in Python varying the values of mean, standard deviation and weight of this two distribution.

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data
import time
import xlwt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from sklearn import datasets

def Puxa_Preco(ticker,start_date,end_date,lag):    
    dados= data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date, end_date )

    from sklearn import datasets
    data_set =  np.log(dados['Close'])-np.log(dados['Close'] .shift(lag))

    data_set = data_set.fillna(method='ffill') 
    data_set = data_set.dropna() 

    y = pd.DataFrame()
    y=data_set

    x = np.arange(len(y))
    size = len(y)
    print(y)
    return y

def mixnormal_cdf(distribuicao, weight1, mean1, stdv1,weight2, mean2, stdv2):
    """
    CDF of a mixture of two normal distributions.
    """
    return (weight1*st.norm.cdf(distribuicao, mean1, stdv1) +
            weight2*st.norm.cdf(distribuicao, mean2, stdv2))

def Objetivo(X,distribuicao):
    peso_dist_1 = X[0]
    mi1 = X[1]
    sigma1 = X[2]
    peso_dist_2 = 1-X[0]
    mi2 = X[3]
    sigma2 = X[4]

    stat2, pvalue = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf,
                                args=(peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1,peso_dist_2, mi2, sigma2))
    ''' Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test, to test whether or not the data is from a given distribution. The 
        returned p-value indicates the probability that the data is from the given distribution, 
        i.e. a low p-value means the data are likely not from the tested distribution.
        Note that, for this test, it is necessary to specify shape, location, and scale parameters,
        to obtain meaningful results (c,loc,scale). 

        stat2:     the test statistic, e.g. the max distance between the
        cumulated distributions '''

    return -pvalue

ticker = 'PETR4.SA'
start_date  = '2010-01-02'      #yyyy-mm-dd
end_date    = '2015-01-02'

for lag in range(1,503):

    distribuicao = Puxa_Preco(ticker,start_date,end_date,lag)
    n = len(distribuicao)

    ChuteInicial=[0.3,0.0010,0.0010,-0.0030,0.0830]                                      #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, mi2, sigma2
    test = [0.2,0.0020,0.0110,0.8,-0.0020,0.0230]
    Limites = ([0,1],[-50,+50],[0,+50],[0,1],[-50,+50],[0,+50])                              #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, peso_dist_2,mi2, sigma2
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Validation Test:")

    print(-Objetivo(test,distribuicao))                                             #the value should be around -0.90 to verify that the objective function it is ok

    solution = minimize(fun=Objetivo,x0=ChuteInicial,args=distribuicao,method='SLSQP',bounds = Limites)             #minimize - p-valor
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("solution:")
    print(solution)
```

Finding the following solution:

```
         fun: -8.098252265651002e-53
         jac: array([-2.13080032e-35,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -1.93307671e-34, 7.91878934e-35])
     message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
        nfev: 8
         nit: 1
        njev: 1
      status: 6
     success: True
           x: array([ 0.3  ,  0.001,  0.001, -0.003,  0.083])
```

But I know that the correct answer should be something like (test) :
[0.2,0.0020,0.0110,0.8,-0.0020,0.0230]  producing a p-value of 0.90

Seems to me that it is running only a few simulations and since it is not changing the p-value it stops.

**Is there a way that I can ensure that the "minimize" will stop only after finding a p-value greater than 0.9 ?
Can someone please help me?**

I tried using the minimize considering Nelder Mead method, and seems more accurate but not even close to the 0.9 p-value that should be the answer and I don't know if the Nelder Mead method considers the limits that I provided.

```
#solution = minimize(fun=Objetivo,x0=(ChuteInicial),args=distribuicao,method='Nelder-Mead',bounds = Limites,options={'int':1000000})
```

Comment: I tried quite a bit to solve your error but to no luck. I am not a statistician, but I thought parameter estimation (means and std) is generally done by maximum likelihood estimation and not by minimizing p-value.

Comment: the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test that I perform verify whether or not the data is from a given distribution, so it is a good way to verify the distribution. I believe it is possible to use the maximum likelihood too.

Comment: Did you try anything simpler?, it looks like the distribuicao variable is more like normally distributed than bi-normal (for atleast first 5 lags). wondering if you tried fitting with a simple normal dist and get mean and std. Another point wrt to how you define the constraints, I think "lambda x:np.array(ChuteInicial[2])" should be more like "lambda x: x[2]", as stated on the scipy minimize function documentation. With simplier distribution, you can also try other optimization methods such unconstrained ones like "Nelder-Mead" ( I had success with ur data for atleast some lags).

Comment: @plasmon360, I edited the code I put in a simpler way now, considering only the limits.
Unfortunantely for this case I must consider the bi-normal distribution because it is the all base of my study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By able to minimize the k-s statistic instead of p-value and other modifications in defining the cdf function, I think I was able to estimate the parameters. Here is my code and the optimized parameter estimates. I got the idea to minimize the k-s statistic from this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250298633_Minimum_Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test_statistic_parameter_estimates)

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data
import time
import xlwt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from sklearn import datasets

def Puxa_Preco(ticker,start_date,end_date,lag):    
    dados= data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date, end_date )

    data_set =  np.log(dados['Close'])-np.log(dados['Close'] .shift(lag))

    data_set = data_set.fillna(method='ffill') 
    data_set = data_set.dropna() 

    y = pd.DataFrame()
    y=data_set

    x = np.arange(len(y))
    size = len(y)

    return y

def mixnormal_cdf(distribuicao, weight1, mean1, stdv1,mean2, stdv2):
    ## CDF of a mixture of two normal distributions.

    return (weight1*st.norm.cdf(distribuicao, mean1, stdv1) +
            (1-weight1)*st.norm.cdf(distribuicao, mean2, stdv2))

def Objetivo(X, distribuicao):
    stat2, pvalue = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf, args=X)
    return stat2

ticker = 'PETR4.SA'
start_date  = '2010-01-02'      #yyyy-mm-dd
end_date    = '2015-01-02'

for lag in range(1,10):
    distribuicao = Puxa_Preco(ticker,start_date,end_date,lag)

    ChuteInicial=[0.2,0.0020,0.0110,-0.0020,0.0230]                                      #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, mi2, sigma2

    Limites = ([0,1],[-0.1,+0.1],[0,None],[-0.1,0.1],[0,None])                              #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, peso_dist_2,mi2, sigma2

    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Intial Guess")
    print(" weight1: {:.4f}, mean1: {:.4f}, stdv1: {:.4f}, mean2: {:.4f}, stdv2: {:.4f}".format(*ChuteInicial))
    ks_stat, p_value = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf, args=ChuteInicial)
    print("k-s stat: {}, p-value: {}".format(ks_stat, p_value))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    solution = minimize(fun=Objetivo,x0=ChuteInicial,args=(distribuicao), method='SLSQP',bounds = Limites, options={'ftol':1e-12})

    print("Optimized Solution:")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(solution.message)
    ks_stat, p_value = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf, args=solution.x)
    print("Optimized k-s stat: {}, p-value: {}".format(ks_stat, p_value))
    print("Optimized weight1: {:.4f}, mean1: {:.4f}, stdv1: {:.4f}, mean2: {:.4f}, stdv2: {:.4f}".format(*solution.x))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

which results in

```
 LAG: 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intial Guess
 weight1: 0.2000, mean1: 0.0020, stdv1: 0.0110, mean2: -0.0020, stdv2: 0.0230
k-s stat: 0.016419395777755863, p-value: 0.9027260234690881
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimized Solution:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimization terminated successfully.
Optimized k-s stat: 0.014896801186217778, p-value: 0.952748910069967
Optimized weight1: 0.2016, mean1: 0.0016, stdv1: 0.0108, mean2: -0.0017, stdv2: 0.0227
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAG: 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intial Guess
 weight1: 0.2000, mean1: 0.0020, stdv1: 0.0110, mean2: -0.0020, stdv2: 0.0230
k-s stat: 0.0791846286223467, p-value: 5.496852766236095e-07
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimized Solution:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimization terminated successfully.
Optimized k-s stat: 0.013690695822088705, p-value: 0.978164746056248
Optimized weight1: 0.2291, mean1: -0.0047, stdv1: 0.0125, mean2: -0.0012, stdv2: 0.0351
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAG: 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intial Guess
 weight1: 0.2000, mean1: 0.0020, stdv1: 0.0110, mean2: -0.0020, stdv2: 0.0230
k-s stat: 0.13436209329730314, p-value: 2.533666062868497e-19
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimized Solution:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Optimization terminated successfully.
Optimized k-s stat: 0.01622740259609401, p-value: 0.9106251238446841
Optimized weight1: 0.2638, mean1: -0.0058, stdv1: 0.0199, mean2: -0.0020, stdv2: 0.0433
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: tk you for the help. This code ran much better now, and I didn't know that article that you mentioned it will be in great help !
But I still have some cases that produce p-value much smaller than considered as my significance level or k-test that are not so precise.

Is there any way that I can continue running the minimize until I get p-value greater than 0.9 or k-test smaller than 0.02 ?

Comment: Glad to help. In the edited code (just now), I added an option called 'ftol' which changes the ftol value from 1E-6 to 1E-12. I think this improved the result (please verify this). if not, you can try changing other SLSQP options as mentioned here.. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp

Comment: @Raphael Khalil If this answers your question. please consider "Upvoting" and/or "Accepting" the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done ! Many Tks !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to ensure that, but it is not the most intelligent way...

```
  for lag in range(1,10):
     distribuicao = Puxa_Preco(ticker,start_date,end_date,lag)
     delta1 = 0
     delta2 = 0
     delta3 = 0
     for j in range(1,101): 
        ChuteInicial=[0.05+delta1,0.0010+delta2,0.0010+delta3,-0.0030+delta2,0.0830+delta3]                                      #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, mi2, sigma2

        Limites = ([0,1],[-0.5,+0.5],[0,None],[-0.5,0.5],[0,None])                              #peso_dist_1, mi1, sigma1, peso_dist_2,mi2, sigma2

        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("------------------------------------Lag " + str(lag) + " -------------------------------------")
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Intial Guess")
        print(" weight1: {:.4f}, mean1: {:.4f}, stdv1: {:.4f}, mean2: {:.4f}, stdv2: {:.4f}".format(*ChuteInicial))
        ks_stat, p_value = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf, args=ChuteInicial)
        print("k-s stat: {}, p-value: {}".format(ks_stat, p_value))
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

        solution = minimize(fun=Objetivo,x0=ChuteInicial,args=(distribuicao), method='SLSQP',bounds = Limites)             #minimize - p-valor

        print("Optimized Solution:")
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(solution)
        ks_stat, p_value = st.kstest(distribuicao, cdf=mixnormal_cdf, args=solution.x)
        print("Optimized k-s stat: {}, p-value: {}".format(ks_stat, p_value))
        print("Optimized weight1: {:.4f}, mean1: {:.4f}, stdv1: {:.4f}, mean2: {:.4f}, stdv2: {:.4f}".format(*solution.x))
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        if ((p_value <= 0.9) or (ks_stat >= 0.02)):
          delta1 += 0.005
          delta2 += 0.001
          delta3 += 0.001
        else:

          break
```